# Requisições Ajax com a Fetch API fica repetindo

Tags: javascript, ajax, api

Faço uma Requisição Ajax com a Fetch API:

```
  function PostData() {

        var A1_CGC;
        A1_CGC = sessionStorage.getItem('cpf');
        console.log(A1_CGC)
        var inicio, fim, A1_CGC;

           inicio = document.getElementById('inicio').value;
           fim = document.getElementById('fim').value;

           // Default options are marked with *
           fetch('API_AQUI', {
               method: 'POST',
               headers: {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
               body: `inicio=${inicio}&fim=${fim}&A1_CGC=${A1_CGC}`
           }).then(response => response.json().then(data => ({
               data: data,
               status: response.status
           })
           ).then(res => {
               res.data.map(element => {
                   var text = element.PRODUTO;
                   $('.produto-1').append(`<h3>${element.PRODUTO}</h3>`);

               })
               var ContaArray = res.data.length 
                if (!ContaArray) {
                    $('#MensagemZeroFiltro').append(`<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                    Nenhuma compra nesse período de tempo.
                  </div>`)
                }

           })
               )         
}
```

Eu coloco a data de inicio e a data de fim, e ele traz uns dados de acordo com a data quando clico no botão, mas se eu clicar no botao 3 vezes, ele mostra o resultado 3 vezes um abaixo do outro. **Eu quero que ele pare de mostrar mais de uma vez o resultado, quero que mostre apenas uma vez. Ex.: cliquei no botão pra mostrar o resultado, mostrou, ai clico de novo e acontece nada, mas se eu mudar a data, ele deve apagar o resultado anterior e colocar o novo.** Como resolvo isso? tentei usando o `stopImmediatePropagation();` mas não funcionou. Gostaria que ele parasse de mostrar os conteúdos repetidamente e mostrasse só uma vez.

Comment: Olá Maria, a tua pergunta não está clara. Quando dizes _"ele mostra o resultado 3 vezes um abaixo do outro"_ queres que isso aconteça? ou que mostre só o ultimo resultado, ou só o primeiro? queres que faça fetch 3 vezes ou espere pelo primeiro?

Comment: Coloque uma condicional para esse evento   `$(".produto-1").append("<h3>${element.PRODUTO}</h3>");`

Comment: Ou você pode subscrever o resultado da requisição: use `$(".produto-1").html("<h3>${element.PRODUTO}</h3>")`; Dependendo do caso você pode até suspender o envio de requisições condicionando a função `PostData()` verificando o valor de `$(".produto-1")`

Comment: @Sergio Atualizei a pergunta

Comment: @AtilaSilva colocando isso ele nao mostra todos os resultados, mostra apenas um, sendo que pode haver varios

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver jogando o `empty` antes de começar a função `fetch`

```
function PostData() {

        var A1_CGC;
        A1_CGC = sessionStorage.getItem('cpf');

        var inicio, fim, A1_CGC;

           inicio = document.getElementById('inicio').value;
           fim = document.getElementById('fim').value;

           $('.produto-1').empty(); 

           // Default options are marked with *
           fetch('API_AQUI', {
               method: 'POST',
               headers: {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
               body: `inicio=${inicio}&fim=${fim}&A1_CGC=${A1_CGC}`
           }).then(response => response.json().then(data => ({
               data: data,
               status: response.status
           })
           ).then(res => {
               res.data.map(element => {
                   var text = element.PRODUTO;
                   $('.produto-1').append(`<h3>${element.PRODUTO}</h3>`);

               })
               var ContaArray = res.data.length 
                if (!ContaArray) {
                    $('#MensagemZeroFiltro').append(`<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                    Nenhuma compra nesse período de tempo.
                  </div>`)
                }

           })
               )         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Podes criar uma função "com memória" que verifica se os valores mudaram antes de fazer um pedido novo:

```js
const PostData = (function() {
  let A1_CGC, inicio, fim, body, lastBody;
  const config = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
  };
  const erro = `<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Nenhuma compra nesse período de tempo.</div>`;
  return function() {
    A1_CGC = sessionStorage.getItem('cpf');
    inicio = document.getElementById('inicio').value;
    fim = document.getElementById('fim').value;
    body = `inicio=${inicio}&fim=${fim}&A1_CGC=${A1_CGC}`;

    // aqui fica a lógica para evitar pedidos duplicados
    if (body === lastBody) return;
    else lastBody = body;

    // Default options are marked with *
    fetch('API_AQUI', { ...config,
        body: body
      })
      .then(response => ({
        data: response.json(),
        status: response.status
      }))
      .then(res => {
        const produtos = res.data.reduce(
          (html, element) => `${html}<h3>${element.PRODUTO}</h3>`, ''
        );

        if (produtos.length === 0) {
          $('#MensagemZeroFiltro').append(erro);
        } else {
          $('.produto-1').append(produtos);
        }
      });
  }
})();
```